# Invariant Violation on changing route

Tags: react-router, redux, reactjs

I'm using a file upload component, here's an extract of the relevant part:

```
class FileUpload extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        edit_mode: React.PropTypes.bool
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.delete_asset = this.delete_asset.bind(this);
    }

    delete_asset(id, event) {
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
        {this.props.edit_mode ? 
            <button onClick={() => this.delete_asset()}>Delete</button>
            : <span />
        }
        </div>;
    }
}
```

This component is wired up within a `react-router` setup, and on a route change, it's one of several nested componentes of the route target.

Whenever I change the route, I get the following exception, even if `edit_mode` does not change on the route change:

> invariant.js:39 Uncaught Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., >0.1.1.1.$0.1.1.0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a  when using tables, nesting tags like ,
>
> , or , or using non-SVG elements in an  parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.

The exception is not thrown then I omit the `onClick` handler.
Any ideas?